# Application launches with different shades of background color. Not sure what causes this behavior

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, polymer

I am maintaining a Polymer 1 / Cordova app and have run into a problem with background colors. The app is supposed to use #F04E23 as the background color. However it sometimes launches in different shades of red (sometimes orange-red / sometimes red-red). Inspecting the app via dev tools shows that the hex is the same.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/BR04l1h.png]

I have been reading online about color profiles and that different hardware/software configurations could affect the way hex colors are displayed. However in my case I am running the same branch, same build, same server, same browser, same user profile, etc.

My biggest problem is that I cannot consistently reproduce the issue. However I have noticed that this behavior often happens when I launch the app for the first time on my Android device via 'cordova run android --device'.

Does anyone have any experience of ideas of what may be causing this behavior? if so could you point me down the right track?

Comment: Just to be clear your always using the same version of Cordova and it's randomly showing different colors?

Comment: @abraham yes that's correct, 'version 8.1.2' is the output from cordova -v.